# Drupal 8 - Admin content list - return 301 on edit

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Drupal 8 Admin content list return 301 redirect back to content list when we try to click on the "edit" link for specific content type without access to edit screen.

For example:

```
node/448/edit?destination=/admin/content - node type article (works)
node/331/edit?destination=/admin/content - node type books (not work)
```

All of the nodes of this specific node type return 301 redirect back to admin content list.

We are using administrator permission, no custom code made.

Thanks

Comment: basic rule: Try flushing the cache (drupal cr all -> if you've got the drupal console installed)

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in as user/1 ? If not, have you checked the CRUD permissions for the specific book content type for administrator role in admin/people/permissions page?